# C - a NON INT function example?

Tags: c

Unfortunately all of the  " C function examples " I come across are about "int"s (numbers).

I need a STRING example of a function.

This is a INT example:  ( works )

```
int cube(int n){
return n*n*n;
}

int o=1;
o = cube(2);
```

I want a STRING example. I attempted to modify the above .. but I FAILED.

```
char cube(char n){
return n;
}

char *o;
o = cube("string");
```

Comment: A single `char` is not a string.

Comment: You need to do more research about how strings (and pointers) work in C. A good starting point is here: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c/1990/strings/8990/string-literals#t=201706081609476801448

Comment: @Govind Parmar: You are right. But technically, a single char can be a string. A single char with value `'\0'` is a string - an empty one.

Comment: @AnT: No, the *address* of a single char with `\0` is a string, but not that char itself!

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: No. String is defined a sequence of characters terminated by `'\0'`. There's no requirement for it to be represented by an "address" (a pointer). For example, `"Hello World!"` is a string. And it is a `char[13]` array, not a pointer.

Comment: But a single char (like `char foo='B';` or `char zeroc='\0';`) is never a string; however `&zeroc` is a zero-terminated string (but `&foo` is not!)

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: True. `char foo='B';` is not a string. But `char foo=0;` is.

Comment: No, your later foo is **not** a string.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: Yes, it is. There's absolutely no difference is "stringiness" of `char a[1] = { 0 };` and `char b = 0;`. For example, I can legally do `char a, b = 0; strcpy(&a, &b);`

Comment: Please cite the standard if `zeroc` (I mean it, not `&zeroc`) is a string. It is not. A string is of type `char*`, but `zeroc` is of (incompatible) type `char`

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: I already did, actually. **7.1.1/1** "A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character." There absolutely nothing in the standard that would require that `&` (a pointer/an address) for it to be a string. It is you who are supposed to justify your "the *address*" requirement. I have no idea where you got it.

Comment: It is just that `char` and `char*` are incompatible types. Strings are `char*` with an additional property (of being zero-byte terminated). So a string is a *sequence* of `char`-s, not a *single instance*.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: False. Strings are **not** `char *` and have never been! Strings in C are `char [N]` (!) with zero-termination requirement. And eligibility of being a "string" for a single char in C is perfectly equivalent to a `char [1]`. As I said above, `"Hello World!"` is a string. And it is not `char *`, it is `char [13]`.

Comment: But still, the type of `zeroc` is not `char[1]` but `char`

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: So what? The definition of a string requires "contiguous sequence of characters". It does not require `char [1]`. It does not require `char *`.

Comment: But still, for any non-negative integer N, `char[N]` is not the same type as `char` (and could be *decayed* to `char*`)

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: So what? Again, when I said that "strings in C are `char [N]`" I did not mean it as a strict requirement on the type. What I mean is that it should be laid out as a "contiguous sequence of characters" in memory (per standard requirements). Both `char [1]` and `char` satisfy that requirenment. And a sequence of just 1 `char` (`char` or `char [1]`) is still a sequence. As for "could be decayed" - I don't see what it has to do with anything. You are apparently still holding onto your "must be an address" idea, which has no basis in reality.

Comment: I guess we have a language issue. I am not a native English speaker. And `strcpy` is a function on strings, taking `char*` arguments.So passing `zeroc` to it won't compile (because the type of `zeroc` is `char`). However `strcpy(&zeroc,&zeroc)` is legal with address-of operator

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch: Note also, that the same 7.1.1/1 also defines: "A *pointer to a string* is a pointer to its initial (lowest addressed) character." So you seem to mixing the concept of a "string" with the concept of a "pointer to a string". For example, arguments of `strcpy` are *not* strings (!).  Arguments of `strcpy` are *pointers to strings* (as least the RHS must be). How you obtained these pointers: through natural array decay or through explicit `&` - does not matter at all.

Comment: It's really simple to remember: `char` means "(single) `char`acter", `int` is a "(single) `int`eger", etc. A string is definitely _not_ a "single" character. Note that `"a"` isn't a single `char`, but `'a'` (different quotation marks) is.

Comment: @ForceBru: Firstly, we are not talking about `'a'` (which is an `int` in C, BTW). We are talking about `char a = 0;`. And one more time: `char a = 0;` is a valid representation of a string in C. It is an *empty* string (i.e. a struing of zero length). Secondly, a string in C can consist of a sigle character, meaning that there is no mutual exclusivity here. Just because something is "a single character" does not mean that it can't be a string.

Comment: @AnT, I dunno what you were talking about, I was addressing the OP. Now that I've read them, I think the problem is that one has to decide whether one character (no null-terminator or anything!) is a string. Is `'a'` a string? To my mind, it isn't, as well as `char a = 0` because these are _characters_ and not _sequences_ of those. I agree, a string may contain a single character, but only in the case of an _empty_ string, otherwise it's `<char> + '\0'`.

Comment: @ForceBru You comment is self-contradictory. On the one hand, you said that you agree that an empty string can consist of a single `char`. On the other hand, you insist that `char a = 0;` is not a string. This self-contradiction makes it hard to understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: @AnT, there's no self-contradiction: `char *a = "";` is a string that contains a null-terminator only, but `char a = 0;` _is_ that null-terminator. `char *` is different from `char`.

Comment: @ForceBru: This conversation is about *standard C terminology*, as defined in 7.1.1. You, on the other hand, seem to be using some kind of your own termionology. Firtstly, `char *a` is **never** a *string* in standard C terminology. Pointers cannot be strings in C. Strings in C are non-empty sequence of characters. Secondly, by standard definition, `char a = 0;` is a valid empty *string*. You need to read and understand the definitions given in 7.1.1. Until you do, it is a waste of time and space.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very simple example

```
char *return_a_string()
{
    return "string";
}

char *o;
o = return_a_string();
printf("%s\n", o);
```

Beware, however, that if you want to return a non-constant string -- that is, if you want your function to dynamically construct the string it returns -- this is more complicated because you have to (have to!) worry about memory allocation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
char *cube(char *n){
return n;
}

char *o;
o = cube("string");
```

Answer (score 0):

[snprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) is a useful library function taking both integers and strings as argument.

[strdup](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) is a useful POSIX (& Linux) function taking and returning a string.

Here is an example of a function which returns a dynamically allocated string (to be later `free`-d, see [free(3) & malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html)....) and get a string as argument.

```
char* stammer(char *inp) {
 size_t ln = strlen(inp);
 char* res = malloc(2*ln+1);
 if (!res) { perror ("malloc stammer"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
 strcpy(res, inp);
 strcat(res, inp);
 return res;
}
```

So `stammer("foo")` returns a [dynamically allocated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) string containing `"foofoo"`. You are then establishing the *convention* (which you'll better document, at least as some comment) that the returned (pointer) value should be at some later appropriate time passed to `free`.

NB. Read more about arrays decaying into pointers in C. A string is conceptually a zero-terminated array (or sequence) of `char`-s, and practically often a valid pointer into it.

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker. I hope that I am using *stammer* in a correct way. (I had to look in the dictionnary)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that in C a *string* is a sequence of character values terminated by a 0-valued byte.  A `char` object only stores a single character value, not a string.

Strings are stored in *arrays* of `char`:

```
char str[6] = "Hello"; // {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 0}, so str must be *at least* 6 elements wide.
```

Passing a string to a function means passing an array expression as the argument, which will "decay" to a pointer to the first element of the array:

```
foo( str );     // same as &str[0] 
foo( "Hello" ); // string literals are array expressions as well
```

Returning a string from a function means returning a pointer to the first element of the string.

```
char *foo( const char *str )
{
  char *result = do_something_with( str );
  return result;
}

char *bar = foo( "Hello" );
```

You want to be careful, here - you *can't* do something like

```
char *foo( const char *str )
{
  char result[] = "some string";
  return result;
}
```

The `result` array is local to `foo`, and will *cease to exist* once `foo` exits; that means the pointer value you return will be *invalid*, and attempting to use that value in the calling function will result in undefined behavior (your code may work as expected, it may crash, you may get funky output, etc.).

If you want to return a string (meaning a pointer to the first element of an array of `char` containing the string) from a function, then you have to make sure that the memory containing the string has a lifetime beyond that of the function, usually by using dynamic memory:

```
char *upcaseString( const char *str )
{
  size_t len = strlen( str );
  char *result = calloc( len + 1 );
  for ( size_t i = 0; i < len; i++ )
    result[i] = toupper( str[i] );

  return result;
}
```

Alternately, pass the target buffer as an argument to the function:

```
void upcaseString( const char *lower, char *upper )
{
  while ( *lower )
    *upper++ = toupper( *lower++ );
}

int main( void )
{
  char lower[] = "hello";
  char upper[sizeof lower];

  upcaseString( lower, upper );
}
```

Comment: The `upcaseString` function calling `calloc` should pass two arguments to it and check its result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* getstr(const char* str){
     return str;
}

int main(void){
     char* mem; //string buffer
     mem=getstr("hello, world\n"); //save returned string
     printf(mem); //print string buffer
     return 0; //end program
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A string in C is a char* (it's a bit more complex but at this point in your learning let's just call it a char*).

That means your function must have a return type of char* if it needs to return a string.

```
# <include stdio.h> // for print statement in second part of the code
char* iReturnAString() {
    char* str = 'this is a sample string'
    return str;
}
```

The above would return a string in C.
You can also print the result:

```
printf('%s', iReturnAString());
// %s gets replaced with the second argument, assuming it is a string
```

Comment: "*A string in C is a `char*`*" no, no, no. A `char*` is a pointer to `char`. A C-string is an array of `char` holding at least one `'\0'`. Simplifying things down to much, confuses even more.